# Tamil language support for dialogflow bot deployed in google assistant

Tags: dialogflow-es

We would like to add tamil language in our dialogflow bot deployed in google assistant. Is Tamil language supported? Do we have to load any specific libraries.

Answer (score 0):

No Tamil is not part of the supported languages for Dialogflow at the moment. Because Dialogflow is a service you are tied to the supported languages, you can't load any libraries to expand on the supported sets.

https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/reference/language